# Are the files compressed with Gzip always smaller than others not compressed?

Tags: http, web, gzip

Recently, I enable the Gzip compression module for resources access on a server manually. Most files have gotten smaller as expected, but there is a file format that is not smaller but larger - `.woff` font. When I enable the Gzip module, a `.woff` file size with 3.2 KB. Conversely, it is only 2.1KB normally. Why do this happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you search for this topic online or even on SO, you can find many resources discussing it. Weren't they useful for you?

Comment: Hint: The WOFF format stores already compressed data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/WOFF

Comment: Here's another answer too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/455783/compressing-videos-create-even-larger-file

Comment: .woff files are already compressed. Compressed (as well as encrypted) files are slightly _expanded_ by a compressor. However your example of 2.1K going to 3.2K is not at all what's expected. There should only be a very slight increase. 2.10K of random data results in 2.12K after gzip compression. Can you provide the .woff file for which this happens, and the resulting .gz file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compress every kind of data.

Compression usually adds some overhead. But it also removes redundancy. So if you have a file that doesn't have enough redundancy, the achieved compression cannot make up for the overhead introduced by the compression format.

WOFF is a compressed file type. So redundancy has already been removed.